# Is it safe to use Trigger to make it UNIQUE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

i have `data cabang` of table, that is structure :

[image: schema table]

i want to create `data cabang.Main ID` use custom UNIQUE using trigger, i have syntax:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Pembuat ID` BEFORE INSERT ON `data cabang` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`Main ID` = 
    CONCAT(
        NEW.`Main ID`,
        '-',
        RIGHT(
            CONCAT(
                '000000',
                (SELECT count(NEW.`Main ID`) 
                 FROM `data cabang` as `dc` 
                 WHERE 
                    dc.`Main ID` = NEW.`Main ID`
                )+ 1
            )
        ,7)
     )
```

The point is i using Trigger:

1. create Trigger BEFORE INSERT
2. I update NEW.`Main ID` using calculate variables `Main ID` and add 1 value (Like Auto increment)

is this safe if i using that for many insert in one time?

Comment: This will not work. First insert: `1`. No `1`'s existing, so you get -> `1-000001`. Second insert: `1`. No `1`'s existing (as it has been changed to `1-000001`), so you will again get `1-000001` with an error. Also, it is generally a bad idea to change the primary key (as the app that tries to insert `1`, it will lose track of that row the moment it inserts it). If you are absolutely sure you do not need that row again (e.g. if it is a pure logging table), you can do it (if you fix your code to alos find rows starting with `1-`), although there is very rarely a reason not to use autoincrement.

Comment: suppose if there are 1000 people enter data in the table at the same time in that way, is there a problem with my `Main ID`? @Solarflare

Comment: Yes, there will probably be a problem, but it will have not that much to do with your trigger, more with the problem that MySQL will probably stop reacting long before you reach 1000 concurrent active connections. If not, you will still run into problems if 1000 connections write to the same table even without a trigger. But you can actually just test this using any benchmark tool/stress test tool you can find on the internet. Btw, in my 1st comment, I missed the fact that Main Id is not the primary key, so ignore the 2nd half of that comment (but you still need to fix the `WHERE`-condition).

Comment: What is name program for checking that? @Solarflare?, you can answer my question now, because this my answer :)

Comment: The MySQL tools include [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlslap.html), but you can find about 1000 tools that do a similar thing in a wide variety of comfort, operating systems, price range or special features. Picking a specific tool would be just personal preference, and in that spirit, I mentioned mysqlslap not because it is particularly good or preferable, but because it could be considered the closest thing to a default choice as it is related to mysql itself. Btw, if you do this test, it would be interesting to see your result.

Comment: I have test, and why i have error `Error when connecting to server: 1049 Unknown database 'mysqlslap'` of query `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysqlslap --delimiter=";" --query="show databases;" --concurrency=1 --iterations=1` ? @Solarflare